# Period-1 and period-2 period doubling bifurcation.

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

Let us consider the discrete time dynamical system $x_{t+1} = f(x_{t}) = a - 5x_{t}^2$.

It is given that $a>-\frac{1}{20}$ and $x_{t} \in [-1,1]$.

I am trying to see at which value of parameter $a$, the map undergoes the period doubling bifurcation of period 1 point.

Say we calculate the value of $a$, for period one point then $f(x^*) = x^*$ implying $a-5x^2  =x$ implying $x^* = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 20a}}{10}$
Period doubling bifurcation occurs when the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix crosses $-1$. Hence, here its the derivative $f'(x) = -1$ at $x=x^*$ so, through this I obtain $a = \frac{3}{20}$. Is this correct?

Next, for period -2 period doubling bifurcation, we need $f^2(x) = x$, $f^2(x)$ is given by $a-5a^2 -125x^4 + 50ax^2$.

For the period 2 solution we need $f^2(x) = x$ implying $a-5a^2 -125x^4 + 50ax^2 = x$.

and for the period doubling bifurcation we need $(f^2(x))' = -1$ implying $-500x^3 + 100ax = -1$. I am struggling to find the value of $a$ where the period doubling bifurcation occur?

Comment: Note that all points that solve $f(x) = x$ also solve $f(f(x)) = x$. So when you find period-2 points you have to exclude fixed points. Just divide $f(f(x)) - x$ by $f(x) - x$ and you will find true period-2 points. Maybe that will simplify the analysis of $(f^2(x))'$?

Comment: Yes, just found that, cool! @Evgeny [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210467/obtaining-the-equations-after-scaling-and-shifting), related to Henon map, can you help me? we can discuss in [dynamical system and chaos theory chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory)?

Comment: I currently have no idea about this question of yours, sorry.

Comment: No worries! it is just the coordinate change and shifting about transforming a composed map into a Henon map!